# Not getting data from nested json in react-native

Tags: image, react-native, state

i want to get data from nested json.

My json looks like as given below

```
    {
    "id": 2,
    "cover_image": "http://13.233.31.123/media/homepage-banner.jpg",
    "name": " Website",
    "tagline": " IT Right",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "client_name": "Company",
    "start_date": null,
    "end_date": null,
    "technology_frontend": "HTML, CSS, JAVASCRIPT\r\nCMS: WORDPRESS",
    "technology_backend": "PHP",
    "description": "We provide robust and high quality Custom Web Development.\r\nCodism is a global technology and business services consulting firm. We are specialized in servicing business market needs specializing in Web Design and Development, Online marketing and IT Consulting Services to commercial and government customers. We provide staffing and end-to end consulting services for organizations.",
    "gallery": [
        {
            "project": 2,
            "image": "http://localhost/media/gallery_image/homepage-banner.jpg"
        },
        {
            "project": 2,
            "image": "http://localhost/media/projects/gallery_image/software-development.jpg"
        },
        {
            "project": 2,
            "image": "http://localhost/media/projects/gallery_image/New_FRS_Image_Mobile_app_development.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get all the images of gallery. I am not getting how i can do that if i am doing `console.log(this.state.gallery[0])` it is showing first object but while i am doing `console.log(this.state.gallery[0].image)` giving error. my i found somewhere like use state as given `gallery: {
        images: []
      }` so my state is like this. how should i use map to get all details please help. thanks in advance

Comment: how do you setState ?

Comment: thanks for reply and sorry for late. i am setting state like this `.then((responseData) => {
        this.setState({ data: responseData })
        this.setState({ gallery: responseData.gallery })`

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are doing mistake while setState
your state should be like

```
this.state = { data : {} }
```

when you setState on componentDidMount or anywhere so do something like

```
this.setState({ data : jsonData )};
```

after that you can use data on your render method for rendering the images.

```
this.state.data.galley.map(item => <Image source={{item.image}/>);
```

if your jsonData is an array and you want to render first object of array so do like

```
this.state = {data: []};
this.setState({data:jsonData)};
this.state.data[0].galley.map(item => <Image source={{item.image}/>);
```

if your jsonData is an array and you want to render all nested images so do like this.

```
this.state = {data: []};
this.setState({data:jsonData)};
this.state.data.map(data => data.galley.map(item => <Image source={{item.image}/>));
```

Comment: tried last one giving error this.state.data.map is not a function

Comment: use this.state.data.galley.map(item => <Image source={{item.image}/>
it's seem your response is an object not an array

Comment: `(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]0: {project: 2, image: "http://13.233.31.123/media/projects/gallery_image/homepage-banner.jpg"}1: {project: 2, image: "http://13.233.31.123/media/projects/gallery_image/software-development.jpg"}2: {project: 2, image: "http://13.233.31.123/media/projects/gallery_image/New_FRS_Image_Mobile_app_development.jpg"}length: 3__proto__: Array(0)` this is my this.state.data.gallery

Comment: please console the this.state before rendering images let me know are you getting the array in data property

Comment: you mean this.state.data ??

Comment: use this it will work this.state.data.gallery.map(item => <Image source={{item.image}/>);

Comment: and  use the condition  like if ('gallery' in this.state.data)

Comment: render() {
    return (<View>
          {this.state.data.gallery.map(item => <Image source={item.image}/>)}
          </View>

Comment: render(){
if('gallery' in this.state.data){
return (<View> {this.state.data.gallery.map(item => <Image source={item.image}/>)} </View> )
}
return null;
}

Comment: use the condition something like above

Comment: sorry but how to give condition like this

Comment: if an using flatlist it is working then why it is not working with map

Comment: because you did mistake something

Comment: but coming in console.log

Comment: please help i want it with map

Comment: the problem is this when you  call to server for retriveing the data at that time this.state.data is an empty object {} and there is no gallery property in this.state.data  and render method get the error that's why i was saying to use condition

Comment: renderImages =(data) => { if('gallery' in data){ return (<View> {data.gallery.map(item => <Image source={item.image}/>)} </View> ) } return null; } 

use this method in your render method like this.renderImages(this.state.data)

Comment: nope bro showing invalid source thanks for giving me time and support

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have all the images of your state, you can do something like this.

When you use the setState, you can try `setState({...yourJson})` to create a new object of your json in your state.

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse the JSON first like

```
.then((responseData) => {
  newData = JSON.parse(responseData);
  this.setState({ data: newData });
  this.setState({ ... newData.gallery });
})
```